# Changing lua default package

Tags: ubuntu, lua, cmake, default-package

I'm currently running Ubuntu and I'm having a problem with lua. When I try to run my project with cmake, it says `LUA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`.

However, I did install lua, and when I check in my /usr/include folder, I can see that lua is there.
But I have lua50, lua5.1 and lua5.2 folders.

It's not my computer and I can't really know what the guy before me exactly did.

When I execute the command "pkg-config --libs lua", it returns me "-llua50".
And I know it's supposed to return "-llua -lm".

So I think I need to change the lua's default package to use "lua5.2" instead of "lua50", but I don't know how to do it nor if it's the right thing to do.

Do any of you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you installed `liblua5.2-dev` or something of the sort?

Comment: As I said, it's not my computer and I'm not sure of what have been done before me. Do you know how can I check that ?